# Load SQL variable in a Select query combined with a condition check

Tags: sql

Trying to load a declared variable in a SQL select query combined with an EXIST condition check. The condition check works but the variable doesn't get assigned after the condition is tested. Is there a way to do the load and test all in one call?

This doesn't work, the @FK_FilingId value is not valid after the condition check

```
DECLARE @FK_FilingId int;
SET @FK_FilingId = 0;
if( EXISTS( SELECT @FK_FilingId = FilingPacketId FROM tbl_Filingtable WHERE Id = @TrackingId))
BEGIN
    PRINT @FK_FilingId
END
```

This does work, but it's not combined in the condition check that I'd like

```
DECLARE @FK_FilingId int;
SET @FK_FilingId = 0;
SELECT @FK_FilingId = FilingPacketId FROM tbl_Filingtable WHERE Id = @TrackingId
if( @FK_FilingId > 0 )
BEGIN
    PRINT @FK_FilingId
END
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: What happens when you run these two different SQL batches?